# How to scale a raw digitised value of Analog Input card with voltage of range -75mV to +75mV with 24bit resolution?

Tags: voltage

I am trying to scale a raw digitised value of Analog Input card with voltage of range -75mV to +75mV with 24bit resolution.

using y = mx+c

here i have to find m = (y/x)-c

m = 0,075/2^23
m = 8,94E-09

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unclear if *raw digitised value[s]* have already been collected, or if you intend to pre-condition the input signal (-75mV to +75mV) so that the *Analog Input card* gives you a digitized result having 24-bit resolution? If you wish to amplify the input signal by **m**, you should also find the ADC-card's internal reference level (voltage).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have to read between the line to  understand, but you have an ADC of 24bit where the minimum value is -75mV and the maximum value is 75mV. And you want to convert it's digital 24 bit to a float using linear interpolation.

So you can say you have the following ratio (ADC->V)
0 -> -0.075
2^24 ->  0.075

V= m ADC+c

m= (0.075-(-0.075))/2^24=0.150/2^24 (so your m is right)

c=-2^23.

I'm not sure this is your question since you can verify it by yourself by replacing any values and seeing it perform as you expect. So the answer, right now is Yes, that's right.